# find bmp in a .bin file

Tags: c#, search, header, offset

After searching for weeks I cant seem to figure out a solution to my problem. What I would like to do is open a form with a RichTextBox, press a load button and load a `.bin`
file to search. Then, have a radio button to select either `jpeg` or `bmp` & in the RichTextBox, display all jpeg's or bmp's -- not the images, just the offset locations.

For example, "jpg found at 0x00002311" which is the offset where ÿØÿà starts, or "bmp found at 0x00009382" witch is where BM starts in the selected `.bin` file.

This is where I'm at: it finds one `bmp` or `jpeg` and displays a count, but not the offset. I need it to find all images and offsets.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog dlgOpen = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
       try
        {
            long count = 0; string line;
            List<String> LinesFound = new List<string>();
            dlgOpen.Filter = "All files(*.*)|*.*";
            dlgOpen.InitialDirectory = "C://bin";
            dlgOpen.Title = "Load";

            if (dlgOpen.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                textBox5.Text = dlgOpen.FileName;
            {
                var sr = new StreamReader(dlgOpen.FileName, Encoding.Default);

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("ÿØÿà"))
                        richTextBox1.Text = ("JPEG Found at address") + count++;
                    else if (line.Contains("BM"))
                        richTextBox1.Text = ("BMP Found at address") + count++;
                }
             }
          }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error in reading file");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? You've got your `{` in the wrong place. It doesn't even compile.

Comment: I deleted some of my "if (line.Contains("  ")). to shorten the post. if you remove 1 } from the bottom and add one } above the catch it should be ok.

Comment: You can edit the question to fix it yourself.

Comment: sorry, im new to asking for help

Comment: What is the format of those `.bin` files? If for example, they are in ELF format, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format, you should write a parser (or find an open source one) to parse them. With a proper parser, locating images inside is pretty easy.

Comment: If you're scanning a file searching for binary data, you shouldn't perform a string search, you need to see the file as binary (as an array of **bytes**). It seems you're assuming a Windows-1252 or UTF-8 encoding for your .BIN file, and you may find false positives because this "text vision" of a binary file.

Comment: I started out trying to scan as an array of bytes with C#. But I had many errors trying to get my task done. I tried a more simple method I knew would not be as accurate but figured along the way I would learn and update. The bin file's do have many ELFs in them but the images im scanning for are not hard to get in them.im just trying to make my own utility to map out the pictures in the .bin's.

Comment: The thing is you __have to__ use a binary approach because the number of images you find may vary depending on the text encoding if you use a string search.

Comment: Yes, but at the moment I don't know how to start the process. So my only idea is to make as many jpeg headers and other headers to give the program more definitions to work with. i could have 20 differant definitions for jpeg. i could also make them 16 bit just to make more. im sure that would kill my scan times but as i go along i will refine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that [StreamReader.Readline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is looking for text not binary data.

A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n").

You need to do a binary search.  Try starting with:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dlgOpen.FileName);
```